# Altering Print Conditions

Tags: python

How can I alter this code so that it only prints when split[1] equals e.g. x and not y?

```
file=sys.argv[1]
data=open(file).readlines()
for line in data:
  split=line.split()
  print split[1], split[4], split[5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`if`, `elif` and `else`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) as required. For example:

```
file=sys.argv[1]
data=open(file).readlines()
for line in data:
  split=line.split()
  if split[1]=="x":
    print split[1], split[4], split[5]
```